# How can I specialize a C++ template for a range of integer values?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to have a template specialization based on a range of values instead of just one? I know the following code is not valid C++ code but it shows what I would like to do.  I'm writing code for a 8-bit machine, so there is a difference in speed for using ints and chars.

```
template<unsigned SIZE>
class circular_buffer {
   unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
   unsigned int head; // index
   unsigned int tail; // index
};

template<unsigned SIZE <= 256>
class circular_buffer {
   unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
   unsigned char head; // index
   unsigned char tail; // index
};
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try [std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<unsigned SIZE>
class circular_buffer {

    typedef typename
        std::conditional< SIZE < 256,
                          unsigned char,
                          unsigned int
                        >::type
        index_type;

    unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
    index_type head;
    index_type tail;
};
```

If your compiler doesn't yet support this part of C++11, there's equivalent in [boost libraries.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/conditional.html)

Then again, it's easy to roll your own (credit goes to KerrekSB):

```
template <bool, typename T, typename F>
struct conditional {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename F>  // partial specialization on first argument
struct conditional<false, T, F> {
    typedef F type;
};
```

Comment: I have to say, this is useful.

Comment: A trait like `std::conditional` is trivial to write yourself, so you don't really need any libraries if you don't have it: `template <bool, typename T, typename> struct conditional { typedef T type; }; template <typename T, typename U> struct conditional<false, T, U> { typedef U type; };`

Comment: Cheers @KerrekSB, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 36):

Use an extra defaulted `bool` parameter:

```
// primary template handles false
template<unsigned SIZE, bool IsSmall = SIZE <= 256>
class circular_buffer {
   unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
   unsigned int head; // index
   unsigned int tail; // index
};

// specialization for true
template<unsigned SIZE>
class circular_buffer<SIZE, true> {
   unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
   unsigned char head; // index
   unsigned char tail; // index
};
```

Comment: I'd be happier if `IsSmall = SIZE <= 256` had parens in it somewhere

Comment: @MooingDuck like this? `IsSmall = (SIZE <= 256)`

Comment: @MooingDuck no need. `<` is less than by default. That's why there is the `template` disambiguator. Confusingly `>` is close template by default and you need parens for that. C++ is great, isn't it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: If it was _needed_ I would have edited the question.  I just said I'd be _happier_.  You still got the +1 though.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible option:

```
template <unsigned SIZE>
struct offset_size {
    typedef typename offset_size<SIZE - 1>::type type;
};

template <>
struct offset_size<0> {
    typedef unsigned char type;
};

template <>
struct offset_size<257> {
    typedef unsigned int type;
};

template<unsigned SIZE>
class circular_buffer {
   unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
   typename offset_size<SIZE>::type head; // index
   typename offset_size<SIZE>::type tail; // index
};
```

([Ideone example](http://ideone.com/vYPow))

Comment: You're such a sadist, it's so cruel w.r.t. the compiler. Try to compile `offset_size<MAX_INT>`, the compiler will have to instantiate billions of template classes!

Comment: Indeed, if you're not careful with this technique you will trigger `error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of ___` (500 by default on gcc).

Answer (score 0):

I hate how messy dealing with types can be so I propose something a bit simpler, leveraging `constexpr`. This variant allows for differing behavior when a varying type is not required and addresses the need to fit within a range and not just one side of a value:

```
template<bool> struct If;

constexpr bool InClosedRange(std::size_t Value, std::size_t Lower, std::size_t Upper)
{
    return (Lower <= Value) && (Value <= Upper);
}

// Usage:
template<size_t Width, If<true>>
class Foo;

template<size_t Width, If<InClosedRange(Width, 1, 41)>>
class Foo { /* ... */ };

template<size_t Width, If<InClosedRange(Width, 42, 142)>>
class Foo { /* ... */ };
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516959/929315