# How can I specialize a C++ template for multiple ranges of integer values?

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements, template-specialization

I'm trying to create a template class for handling bit streams. I'd like to have an underlying integer type declared in the template that would resolve to either `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`, depending on the template argument (an int, number of bits). I found the two answers regarding this subject ([How can I specialize a C++ template for a range of integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019232/how-can-i-specialize-a-c-template-for-a-range-of-integer-values) and [Integer range based template specialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510514/integer-range-based-template-specialisation)) and implemented the following code:

```
template<int BITS>
class MyClass {
   typedef typename
      std::conditional< BITS <= 8,  uint8_t,
      std::conditional< BITS <= 16, uint16_t,
      std::conditional< BITS <= 32, uint32_t, uint64_t > > >::type
         int_type;
    ...
}
```

In my program, I instantiate `MyClass<32>`, but when compiling this, I'm getting the following error:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘MyClass<32>::int_type {aka std::conditional<false, short unsigned int, std::conditional<true, unsigned int, long unsigned int> >}’
```

If I'm instantiating `MyClass<8>` instead, everything works. So it looks like only the first level of `std::conditional` is actually expanded.

Any idea how to do this correctly?

**Edit:** I haven't stated this before, but I'm looking for a solution which would also work for any bit size instantiation (as long as it's 64 bits at most). So I'd like `MyClass<27>` to work as well (selecting `uint32_t`).

Comment: either use std::conditional_t or add "typename cond<>::type" to nested conditionals too

Comment: _"Any idea how to do this correctly?"_ Yes, you need to use `::type` for every `std::conditional`; it doesn't magically become optional and the compiler guess what you want, just because it's nested.

Comment: Massimiliano's suggestion works. Can you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your edit and make your original code work.

```
template<int BITS>
class MyClass {
   using int_type =
      typename std::conditional< BITS <= 8,  uint8_t,
      typename std::conditional< BITS <= 16, uint16_t,
      typename std::conditional< BITS <= 32, uint32_t, uint64_t >::type >::type >::type;
   public:
   int_type i;
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have in the code now, based on Massimiliano's comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest the better:

```
template<unsigned nbits> struct uint {};

template<> struct uint<8> { using type = uint8_t; };
template<> struct uint<16> { using type = uint16_t; };
template<> struct uint<32> { using type = uint32_t; };
template<> struct uint<64> { using type = uint64_t; };

template<int nbits>
struct MyClass { using int_type = typename uint<(nbits/8)*8>::type; };
```

Comment: @UKMonkey just to be sure, it is _not_ sarcastic, right?

Comment: Nice, but he has edited the terms in the question. He's looking for something that works for any value between 0 and 64 (inclusive).

Comment: A nice solution, but it only works for the specified bit sizes, plus you omitted a `typename`. The correct last name should be `struct MyClass { using int_type = typename uint<nbits>::type; };`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is already provided in [the answer by @super](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48173417/434551).

It was instructive for me to understand the error message.

You have defined `int_type` as:

```
typedef typename
  std::conditional< BITS <= 8,  uint8_t,
  std::conditional< BITS <= 16, uint16_t,
  std::conditional< BITS <= 32, uint32_t, uint64_t > > >::type
     int_type;
```

It works correctly for `BITS <= 8` since the

```
  std::conditional< BITS <= 16, uint16_t,
  std::conditional< BITS <= 32, uint32_t, uint64_t > >
```

part is essentially ignored.

Let's say you use `MyClass<16>`. Then, the `uint8_t` is ignored. What you have for `int_type` is:

```
  std::conditional< BITS <= 16, uint16_t,
  std::conditional< BITS <= 32, uint32_t, uint64_t > >
```

That can be simplified to:

```
  std::conditional< true, uint16_t,
  std::conditional< true, uint32_t, uint64_t > >
```

Unfortunately, that is the type you get without using `std::conditional<...>::type`.

Let's say you use `MyClass<32>`. Then what you have for `int_type` is:

```
  std::conditional< BITS <= 16, uint16_t,
  std::conditional< BITS <= 32, uint32_t, uint64_t > >
```

That can be simplified to:

```
  std::conditional< false, uint16_t,
  std::conditional< true, uint32_t, uint64_t > >
```

That is the type you get.

You can get some idea of those types by printing name of the corresponding `type_info` objects.

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<int BITS>
struct MyClass
{
   typedef typename
      std::conditional< BITS <= 8,  uint8_t,
      std::conditional< BITS <= 16, uint16_t,
      std::conditional< BITS <= 32, uint32_t, uint64_t > > >::type
         int_type;
};

int main()
{
   typename MyClass<8>::int_type a;
   std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

   typename MyClass<16>::int_type b;
   std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;

   typename MyClass<32>::int_type c;
   std::cout << typeid(c).name() << std::endl;

   typename MyClass<60>::int_type d;
   std::cout << typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output, using g++ 5.4.0:

```
h
St11conditionalILb1EtS_ILb1EjmEE
St11conditionalILb0EtS_ILb1EjmEE
St11conditionalILb0EtS_ILb0EjmEE
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at **Boost.Integer**: its [Integer Type Selection](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html) does exactly what you are looking for. In your case you should use `boost::uint_t<N>::least`:

```cpp
#include <boost/integer.hpp>

template<int BITS>
class MyClass {
   using int_type = typename boost::uint_t<BITS>::least;
};
```